# TSQL 2012 Format String Literal with AM and PM

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, datetime-format

I have been using the format() function string literal available in SQL Server 2012 to great effect. Unfortunatly, I cannot find any good resources to help me bring out the AM/PM of a formated date time literal. I am using this code:

```
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) BETWEEN '2013-03-10' AND '2013-11-03'
        OR CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) BETWEEN '2014-03-09' AND '2014-11-02'
        OR CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) BETWEEN '2015-03-08' AND '2015-11-01'
        OR CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) BETWEEN '2016-03-13' AND '2016-11-06'
        OR CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) BETWEEN '2017-03-12' AND '2017-11-05'
        OR CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) BETWEEN '2018-03-11' AND '2018-11-04'
        OR CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) BETWEEN '2019-03-10' AND '2019-11-03'
        THEN format(dateadd(hh, -4, GETDATE()), 'MMMM d, yyyy h:mm EDT')
    ELSE format(dateadd(hh, -5, GETDATE()), 'MMMM d, yyyy h:mm EST')
END as process_finished
```

To get this format:

> November 20, 2013 1:28 EST

When of course, I want it to look like this:

> November 20, 2013 1:28PM EST

Notes on the code: I am using the date ranges to properly show daylight saving time and standard time for the US East Coast.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the AM/PM designator [`tt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#ttSpecifier) in your format string.

```
    THEN format(dateadd(hh, -4, GETDATE()), 'MMMM d, yyyy h:mmtt EDT')
ELSE format(dateadd(hh, -5, GETDATE()), 'MMMM d, yyyy h:mmtt EST')
```

See the [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) page for details.

Comment: I have been looking for a page like that forever! Thanks, this is the answer I need. I will claim as an answer when Stackoverflow.com let's me.